# from c9.io can't push to a repo I created and own

Tags: git, github

so, I know that I'm missing something obvious here .. I am an owner member of an organisation, and recently created a repo.

I then cloned and pulled the repo using ssh, made some changes and tried to push - but I get the error

> Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.112' (RSA) to the
>   list of known hosts. ERROR: Repository not found. fatal: Could not
>   read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

I have tried every setting that I can find in the organisation, but still can't get past this issue.

I have never had any problems with my personal account on either github or bitbucket

However, if I clone using https, and supply username and password when pushing, then I can push without problems.

This makes me suspect that there is something with my ssh keys (but they work with a personal repo without problems)

Would appreciate some help / guidance / slap round the ears telling me how stupidly obvious the solution is ;)

**update #1**

It has to be my machine - if I logon to another machine, I can pull, commit and push without any problem at all

The "machine" I am having problems with is a c9 online account. This account allows me to pull and push to any personal repo on github, just not organisation repos

Comment: I have seen this error using Bitbucket when I had not given it my public SSH cert (and hence it did not trust anything coming from my machine).  Maybe you could check the same in Github.

Comment: thanks - but I can't find a place to add my ssh cert to the organisation. github obviously has my ssh creds somewhere, as it works with my personal repos, and as I am an owner of the org, I thought it would use my credentials

Comment: Here, have an upvote, I'm curious to see how you resolve this.

Comment: please share the commands you tried.

Comment: Did you reproduce this with another, new checkout? Is the remote setup in your checkout correctly? Can you fetch remote?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's a problem with C9 now. I am connected to github in c9 as a "user", but there is no way to add an org

As I just mentioned in the "update#1" I can get it to work no problems in a non-c9 environment

Comment: but, to answer your questions: Yes, I created a new workspace in c9, cloned the repo and tried to push. same problem. I *can* fetch the remote, just not push

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem - in my *personal* settings on github, under "*Authorized applications*", I clicked on the "*cloud9*"  icon, and saw that under "*Organization access*" one of the orgs I belong to needed to be granted access.

granted access, all is good

thanks for the help, comments and suggestions